# Segment.selectedSegmentIndex is always returning a zero

Tags: ios

I'm trying to use a Segmentcontroller.
When a button is press my callback gets call,
but when i use .selectedSegmentIndex to see what button was press, it returns a zero.
code

```
-(IBAction)changeSeg{
    int g;
    g=Segment.selectedSegmentIndex;

    if(Segment.selectedSegmentIndex == 0){
        UpperLower=0;
    }
    if(Segment.selectedSegmentIndex == 1){
        UpperLower=1;
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure `Segment` is the correct control?

Answer (score 0):

I think the method should look like this

```
- (IBAction)ChangeSeg:(UISegmentedControl *)sender {
    if(sender.selectedSegmentIndex == 0){
        UpperLower=0;
    } else if(sender.selectedSegmentIndex == 1){
        UpperLower=1;
    }
}
```

The sender will have the selectedSegmentIndex that was chosen.